# How to allocate difference in minutes over multiple days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently making a table to represent all of our companies system down times. The main goal is to have a table show every date and the total up% and down%. The main issue I am running into is whenever we have something go down that lasts more than 24 hours, how am I to allocate the appropriate times to the appropriate days?

In our DB, I am working with 4 main fields: DateDown, TimeDown, DateUp, TimeUp. I concat the times together and then found the difference in minutes between the two. Say something went down on 8/12/2019 9:00 and came up 8/15/19 14:00. I find the DATEDIFF in minutes of the two, but am now faced with a total downtime associated to one day rather than allocating to each respective day.

Any tips or pointers? Thank you.

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to split the down time across multiple rows.

Comment: create a cartesian for each day then get different from and to

Comment: @CaiusJard We use SSMS

Comment: @shawnt00 I will give this a try. Thank you!

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I will give this a try as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
--begin row generator block - this generates a list of days over the past year
WITH r (today, tomorrow) AS (
   -- Anchor member definition
   SELECT CAST(CAST(GetDate() as DATE) as DATETIME) AS today, CAST(CAST(GetDate() as DATE) as DATETIME) + 1 AS tomorrow
   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive member definition
   SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, today), DATEADD(day, -1, tomorrow)
   FROM   r
   WHERE  today > GetDate() - 365
),
-- end row generator

-- begin CTE that fixes your downtime table
downtimetable as (
  SELECT
    CAST('2019-07-01' as DATE) datedown, 
    CAST('2019-07-01' as DATE) dateup, 
    CAST('2019-07-01 12:00:00' as DATETIME) as datetimedown, -- fix this so your date and time down columns are a single datetime
    CAST('2019-07-01 13:00:00' as DATETIME) as datetimeup,
    'downupsameday' as descr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '2019-07-01',
    '2019-07-02',
    '2019-07-01 14:00:00',
    '2019-07-02 08:00:00',
    'downovermidnight_10h_8h'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '2019-07-01',
    '2019-07-03',
    '2019-07-01 20:00:00',
    '2019-07-03 06:00:00',
    'downovertwomidnights_4h_24h_6h'
)
--end CTE that fixes your downtime table 

SELECT 
  CASE
    --downtime starts today and ends today
    WHEN d.datetimedown >= r.today AND d.datetimeup < r.tomorrow THEN DATEDIFF(minute, d.datetimedown, d.datetimeup)
    --downtime started before today and ends today
    WHEN d.datetimedown < r.today AND d.datetimeup < r.tomorrow THEN DATEDIFF(minute, r.today, d.datetimeup)
    --downtime started today and ends after tomorrow
    WHEN d.datetimedown >= r.today AND d.datetimeup >= r.tomorrow THEN DATEDIFF(minute, d.datetimedown, r.tomorrow)
    --downtime started before today and ends after tomorrow
    ELSE 1440
  END as minutes,
  *
FROM   
  r
  INNER JOIN downtimetable d ON r.today BETWEEN d.datedown and d.dateup
ORDER BY r.today
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366) --this is needed because the default recursion for the row generator is 100
```

---

I forgot to put a note to how it works. Once the generator has made a list of dates (every day at midnight) for the past year it is joined to your table of up and downs with "between". If a down date is on eg day 1 and up date is on day 3 the join condition will cause that down/up data row to repeat so there are 3 instances of it, one for each day. Then the case when just looks at the dates involved and that's how we break your ups and downs into "how long was it down for today (today being the date from the row generator not the updown table)"

Now what you need to do is: edit the parts between the "begin/end the CTE that fixes your downtime table":

You must use the CTE to re-shape your downtime table so that the dates there-in are presented as the date the service went down/up, and the datetime the service went down/up (by datetime i mean the sqlserver datatype that combines the date and the time. )

Ideally you should be storing your dates when things go up and down as a DATETIME type, not having two separate columns (I fear you're storing dates/times as varchar: do *not* do this). The date and the time should be combined in storage because that's how they're most useful (for maths /working with them). To strip the time element from a DateTime, cast it to a date - it's a lot easier/cleaner to go from a DateTime to a Date than go from a date + time separate, to a datetime. I find a time on its own is seldom that useful

Comment: Welcome! I added a note on how it works just under the code because I realised I'd forgotten to do it